# Commandline program affecting subsequent shell output with underlines?

Tags: ssh, putty

[image]

I'm SSHing via Windows PuTTY to my server running Ubuntu Server 12.04. As you can see in the top of the screenshot, the terminal looks normal but when I run Behat (a PHP test automation framework), all subsequent output is underlined. What could be causing this? Is it a Linux issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most modern terminals understand color codes, for example if you run this
 `echo -e '\e[1;33myellow and not stopping!'`, you will have your font set to yellow. This setting applies to the terminal, and not to individual programs that are being run, therefor it can be permanent. The "stop" command is `echo -e '\e[0m'` which resets this and should also work in your case.

Or you can type `reset` which should also return terminals in various states of disrepair to normal.

But you should file a bug with the author of that software, that is not nice behavior.